# Codename One - How to find child components of given parent

Tags: codenameone

I am using Calendar component and I would like to find all CalendarDay buttons in it. I've seen that you can see parent component using getParent() method but how can I get child components?

It would be also great to know how to select all gui components with given UIID.

Answer (score 0):

That particular problem will be better served by deriving `Calendar` and overriding `createDay()` as it won't break with future changes to the [Calendar class](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Calendar.html).

However to answer the question the old way looked like this:

```
int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < childCount ; iter++) {
    Component current = parent.getComponentAt(iter);
    // do something with current
}
```

Note that `getComponentAt(index) != getComponentAt(x,y)`...

But there is a simpler way:

```
for(Component currentChild : parent) {
    // do something with currentChild
}
```